# Is there a shortcut to play the audio preview on Finder?

Tags: finder, preview

I have a bunch of audio files that I need to classify, so I need to play a few seconds of each file and then rename it accordingly. I can do almost all the operations with keyboard shortcuts, except for playing the preview, for that one I need to click on the play button on the center of the preview column.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press the space bar to open quick look, which will automatically play the sound. Space again will close it.